# Ab Initio graph : partioning by key behavior with Replicate

Tags: bigdata, partitioning, ab-initio

I am asking myself a question concerning
Let's suppose I have a flow F which is replicated X times.
All the replicated flows are then Join on the same key but with different datasets each time.

I want the joins to be run in a parallel layout. For this particular case, do I need to use X time the "Partition by key" component or can I put only one at the input of the replicate (instead of 1 per replicate output) ?

TLDR :
Is this graph 
https://ibb.co/hHmk5e
equivalent to 
https://ibb.co/i2NNJz
supposing all joins occur on same key

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Replicate into multiple Partition By Keys. Pay caution to the checkpoints, if you have 3 checkpoints after the replicate consider removing them and placing a single checkpoint before the replicate.